# Highcharts : How to using grouped_categories for csvURL?

Tags: highcharts

I have url get CSV data:
This is a data simple for csvURL:

```
Name, ProcessId, Data, Label
LTS-L01-001, 1-1, 13, 49
LTS-L01-002, 2-1, 36, 48
LTS-L01-002, 2-2, 14, 1
```

I using [group-categories](http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/), work ok on CSV (get by elements).
[img using csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96JyV.png);
I apply this for csvURL, but it not work.

I get data from CSVURL update to categories, because categories dynamic.
I don't keep it. (dataRefreshRate: 5).

[img using csvURL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWLqm.png)

```
var newOption = {
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        chart: {
            type: "column",
            renderTo: eleId
        },
        data: {
            csvURL: url,
            enablePolling: true,
            dataRefreshRate: 5,
            seriesMapping: [{ x: 0, processId: 1, y: 2, label: 3 }],
            complete: function (e) {
                var ds = e.series[0].data, arr = [], arrComplete = [];
                for (var i = 0 ; i < ds.length; i++) {
                    var ind = arr.indexOf(ds[i].name)
                    if (ind < 0) {
                        arr.push(ds[i].name);
                        arrComplete.push({ name: ds[i].name, categories: [ds[i].processId] });
                    }
                    else
                        arrComplete[ind].categories.push(ds[i].processId)
                }
                e.xAxis.categories = arrComplete;
            }
        },
        title: { text: null },
        xAxis: {
            type: "category",
            labels: {
                useHTML: true,
                rotation: -90,
                style: {
                    height: 'auto',
                    padding: '0px 0px 0px 10px',
                    textAlign: 'right'
                }
            },
            categories: [],
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            gridLineColor: '#e6e6e6'
        },
        series: [],
        yAxis: {
            floor: 0,
            ceiling: 100,
            title: { text: null },
            labels: { format: '{value} %' },
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 0,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '12px',
                textAlign: 'center'
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return (
                    '<span class="title-header">' + this.key + ' [' + this.point.processId + ']' + '</span>' +
                    '</br><small style="color:red">' + this.point.label + '</small> ' +
                    '(' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 1) + ' %)');
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 20,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none',
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        color: 'black',
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        textAlign: 'center'
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (
                            '<small style="color:red">' + this.point.label + '</small>' +
                            '</br>' + (Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 0)) + ' %');
                    }
                },
                color: 'green'
            }
        }
    };
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(newOption);
```

Please, helps me. tks.

Comment: Hi Vu Dinh Hung, did you try to use update method on xAxis? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xrz509gs/

Comment: thank you so much. This work.
From this example, I apply this, for our chart.
I see 1 problem, when i set type: category.
<code>
 Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({
                categories: categories,
    type:'category'
            });
</code>
for this name: i set text. But highchart auto change to dateTime.
example: LTS-LCom-1 --> Aug-1.....

Thank for your suggestion.

Comment: Please try to do update without setting xAxis type. If it does not help, please prepare some minimal live example which shows this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use update method on xAxis:

```
    complete: function(e) {
        var categories = [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: [Math.random(), "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }];

        Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].update({
            categories: categories
        });
    }
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xrz509gs/